# MySQL: index statistics dropped when table dropped?

Tags: mysql, tuning, index-statistics

When a table is dropped, are its index statistics also removed?

The reason I ask is that I was hoping to 'prep' the stats by running log playback via the percona-playback tool prior to cutting over from our current production environment.

Thanks.